# how to change the class's property using angular js

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have seen several examples here. But still get confused how to do the following.

I have two screenshots for better understanding.
The first screenshot shows the default view for the mobile phones. But whenever I click the `2nd row (i.e. Rahul Thusso)` it will show the screen like screenshot 2.
And when I click `the back button i.e. <-` the Right panel having details for `Rahul Thusso` will be gone.

I have used `@media .... .master-container-rt{ width: 0%; }` but it is static and will not solve my problem.

By default when the screen loads `master-container-rt{ width: 0%; }` is fine. Clicking the row for `Rahul Thusso`, ideal screen will be `master-container-rt{ width:100%; }`and finally click on the `<-` button `master-container-rt{ width: 0% }` would be fine.

How to achieve it with Angular JS??

[image: Screenshot 1- Default Scree]
Screenshot 1-default Screen

[image]
Screenshot 2-Right panel enabled screen

Comment: Your query is not very clear. Do you want to implement the functionality that is shown in the second screenshot whenever the the row is clicked? and want the things back to normal when the back button is clicked?

Comment: for change class with angularjs, you must use ng-class . ` ng-class="{master-container-rt:  check()}" ' . create function for check. if resault=true, applay class

Comment: @Khoshtarkib is it possible to use ng-class="{master-container-rt: width:100%}" or something can be achieved using a function?

Comment: plz share full html . this needs to be done using ng-class and css

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ng-style` or `ng-class` whichever suits you best. You can use them conditionally also. Following fiddle may help you.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/9326/
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two functions attached to your scope.

```
$scope.showBox = function() {
              $scope.width = "100%"
}

$scope.hideBox = function(){
              $scope.width = "0%";
}
```

then in your html add `ng-style="{width: width}"` to your element that you want to show or hide.
and add `ng-click="showBox()"` and `ng-click="hideBox()"` to the row element and the back button respectively.

Comment: I understand what you say. But I want to change the width of the .master-container-rt class to 100% because it controls the functionality of the right panel totally.